# How to insert chinese character into database

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to add Chinese character in my database. I am adding this 黔西南布依族苗族自治州 and getting this é»”è¥¿å—å¸ƒä¾æ
any help?

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-16');

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');  

if(isset($_POST['totalprice'])){

        $totalprice=$_POST['totalprice'];
        $price=$_POST['price'];
        $qty=$_POST['count'];
        $color=$_POST['color'];
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $address=$_POST['address'];
        $province=$_POST['province'];
        $city=$_POST['city'];
        $region=$_POST['region'];
        $payment=$_POST['payment'];
        $message=$_POST['message'];
        $model=$_POST['model'];
        $commodity=$_POST['commodity'];
        $totalprice=$_POST['totalprice'];
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $description='';

        $sql="INSERT INTO `orderItems`( `commodity`, `model`, `color`, `qty`, `total`) VALUES ('$commodity','".$model."','".$color."','".$qty."','".$totalprice."')";
           $db->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: now question marks are getting stored in the database, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

Please use **utf8mb4** when you insert to table

```
set username utf8mb4; INSERT INTO table_name (aaa,VAL);
```

you can just do it by alter table field from phpmyadmin and set type to  **utf8mb4**.

```
mysqli_query("SET character_set_results=utf8mb4", $db);
```

Sometimes MySQL's utf8 does not support.This is because of a small number of Chinese characters that require 4-byte UTF8 characters.So **utf8mb4**  used.

Answer (score -1):

change that column's **charset/collection** from Default charset to **utf8**

then you can insert anything in that column